# How to open in interface user the result of grep?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, grep

For a couple of weeks, i create a script (bash) to find some files with the terminal's mac.

How to open the results in a folder interface of mac with all the files found ? (ie like the finder of mac)

I try the command xargs with the command open but each file found is open, i want to **find all the result in a same screen** because i can have a preview, etc.

this is my script :

```
grep -irEl --exclude-dir={"*sys"} "word to find" /Users/ponne/Desktop/Test | xargs ls -lah
```

Comment: Please update the tags to show that this is mac-specific. This is really a question about finding a Mac GUI that shows a specified list of files - once you know that, just replace your `ls` with that. It's not really a bash/terminal/grep question at all.

Answer (score 0):

does this solve your problem?

```
ls -alh $( grep -irEl --exclude-dir={"*sys"} "word to find" /Users/ponne/Desktop/Test)
```

Comment: No it doesn't solve my problem. 

i execute your code but it doesn't answer to my need / requirement.

I would open all the result in a same window. (i'm in MacOS to execute the script in the terminal and want the result open in a window finder)